# What are the chromatic polynomial of these graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

What are the chromatic polynomial of these graphs?

[image]

I first add the edge fk, and Then I contract this edge and then use the following theorem  $P(G)=P(G^{+}_{e})+P(G^{++}_{e})$, where e is the edge fk. Then I found that the contraction of the edge fk is two K3 graph which connect at one vertex. But I don't know the chromatic polynomial of $G^{+}_{e}$
I use the following theorem
If graph G is unin of $G_1$ and $G_2$, and $G_1 \cap G_2=K_n$, then  $P(G,a)=P(K_n,a).P(G_1,a)\over a(a-1)...(a-n+1)$ , where a is rhe number of colors

Comment: That's not how this site works. You are meant to help us give you the most useful answer by telling us what you know about the problem, what methods you have learned, what happened when you tried them, where you got stuck, how you came across the problem in the first place, and so on. When in doubt, consult the Help menu to learn "How to ask a good question".

Comment: Yes, thank you, ok. I first add the edge fk, and Then I contract this edge and then use the following theorem  $P(G)=P(G^{+}_{e})+P(G^{++}_{e})$, where e is the edge fk. Then I found that the contraction of the edge fk is two K3 graph which connect at one vertex. But I don't know the chromatic polynomial of $G^{+}_{e}$

Comment: You use the unexplained notations $G^+$ and $G^{++}$. The graph you get by adding the edge $fk$ is composed entirely of triangles. Do you know a way to find the chromatic polynomial of such graphs?

Comment: $G^{+}$ means that the graph that is gained by adding the edge fk, and $G^{++}$ is the graph is gaine by contracting the edge fk. I think the intersection of entirely triangels are the complete graph $K_2$, and I use the following theorem

Comment: The notation should be explained in the body of the question, not in the comments. I don't know what you mean by "the intersection of entirely triangles are the complete graph $K_2$." I don't see any "following theorem". I'm asking whether you know any technique (other than the formula you gave involving $G^+$ and $G^{++}$) for finding chromatic polynomials, any technique that works in simple cases.

Comment: By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Comment: If graph G is unin of $G_1$ and $G_2$, and $G_1 \cap G_2=K_n$, then  $P(G,a)=P(K_n,a).P(G_1,a)\over a(a-1)...(a-n+1)$ , where a is rhe number of colors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133427/discussion-between-darya-and-gerry-myerson).

Comment: OK, but I think it's going to be a lot of work to apply that formula. Instead of trying to apply a formula, just go back to the definition of the chromatic polynomial, and compute it directly. How many ways can you color $f$? Once $f$ is colored, how many ways can you color $g$? And so on.... Sorry, I don't do chat.

Comment: @Gerry , ok thanks a lot for your help and comments

Comment: The formula you give a few comments earlier doesn't have $G_2$ in it, and the denominator is just $P(K_n,a)$, so something's wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by the above theorem of chromatic polynomial
$P(G)=\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda^2-5\lambda+8)$, where $\lambda$ is the number of colors. Then the chromatic number equals 3. @Gerry